# Private variable members of a class shows junk data even after assigning value

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I have a private integer `p` initialized with value 0 and a function `foo` to process it.

```
class C
{
public:
    C();

private:
    unsigned int p = 0;
    unsigned int g = 50;
    void foo();
};

void C::foo()
{
     std::cout << p << std::endl;
     //p shows junk data
     
     std::cout << g << std::endl;
     //g also shows junk data
}

C::C()
{
     p = 5;
}
```

When debugging `foo()`, variable `p` contains junk value even though it should be 5. I'm not sure why it is showing like this. This problem is also seen in other variables in my program.

This is not the same class or code I'm using in my program which is a win32 application but the problem here is the same for it.

For extra information, this is how I handle the messages for my function just in case the problem is with this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM)
{
    C* pThis = NULL;
    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        pThis = (C*)lpcs->lpCreateParams;

        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis));
        return pThis->HandleMessages(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
        pThis = reinterpret_cast<C*>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        return pThis->HandleMessages(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not enough data and scope. You're likely accessing freed/misaligned object or a wrong memory space - especially since you're forcing type by casting. But need more context to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the issue. The problem was that the class object was destroyed after creating the window so the variables which were supposed to be there was non existent, But thanks for trying to help @SomeWittyUsername

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, Could you post an answer to end this thread.It will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

You can only access member variables while the object is still there or else when the object goes out of scope, you will only get garbage values.